# Redirecting to home page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the next following problem in my vue registration. When I click register it redirects me to the home page. Maybe using some conditions could solve this problem. How can I prevent this from happening? Any ideas?
My Javascript:

```
register() {
      firebase 
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.lozinka)
        .then(
        function() {
         console.log('Success'); 
         let id = this.email
          db.collection("user")
          .doc(id)
          .set({
            korisnicko_ime: this.korisnicko_ime,
            email: this.email,
            lokacija: this.lokacija,
            ime_objekta: this.ime_objekta,
            kontakt: this.kontakt,
          })
          .then((doc) => {
                console.log("Saved", doc)
            })
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error...", error);
                if ( store.currentUser=null ) {
                  this.$router.replace({ name: 'Register'});
                }
              });
        
        console.log('Continue'); 
        this.$router.replace({ name: 'Home'});
        
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what you are actually trying to achieve but what you are doing is fireing a request, register your callbacks on the request's promise and **immediately** replace your current route.

```
register() {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.lozinka)
    .then(successCallback)
    .catch(errorCallback);

  this.$router.replace({ name: 'Home'});
}
```

I guess you probably want to wait for the response of your register request and redirect your user based on whether the promise resolved successfully or with an error?

At first you probably should have a deeper look at

- *Promises* with its *async*/*await* syntax
- Using *const* over *let*/*var*

```
async register() {
  try {
    const registerResponse = await firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.lozinka);

    console.log("Success");
    const id = this.email;

    const collectionResponse = await db
      .collection("user")
      .doc(id)
      .set({
        korisnicko_ime: this.korisnicko_ime,
        email: this.email,
        lokacija: this.lokacija,
        ime_objekta: this.ime_objekta,
        kontakt: this.kontakt,
      });

    console.log("Saved", doc);

    // After everything was successfull, redirect to home
    this.$router.replace({ name: 'Home'});

  } catch(error) {
    console.error("Error...", error);

    if ((store.currentUser = null)) this.$router.replace({ name: "Register" });
  }
}
```